# mergExt - Cannot get mergBgTask to continue indefinitely

Tags: livecode

I have followed the documentation, video and demo example, and have attempted to replicate in my own stack in LiveCode.

The command I run after `mergBgTaskStart` sends to itself in 60 seconds, and runs successfully about 2-4 times once the app is in the background.

However I cannot get it to continue beyond these few times. I need the command to run indefinitely until logout or until the app is closed.

Please better explain to be the `mergBgTaskExpired` message and how I can reinitiate my command so as to avoid letting my app slip into suspend.

At present it is set up as follows:

In the main stack:

```
on bgupdate
   mergBgTaskStart
   get_location
end bgupdate

on mergBgTaskExpired pBackgroundTaskIdentifier
   -- Here I have tried inserting bgupdate and/or get_location to reinitiate it without success
   mergBgTaskStop pBackgroundTaskIdentifier
end mergBgTaskExpired
```

The command `get_location` contains "send get_location to me in 60 seconds" and is called via a button on the first card.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind background tasks is to complete a take you started while the app was in the foreground. You can't start a new task while in the background.

If you need to avoid suspending your app you should use one of the UIBackgroundModes as a plist setting. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) for more info.

Comment: Fair enough. Would I need to send the command at a much greater time interval for the suspend to be delayed? It seems that with short time intervals on send that the command stops running after 3-4min on iOS 8.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's changed on iOS 8 but it used to be around 10 minutes. You could use mergNotify to find out when your app is being suspended and create a background task then. But it sounds like the best bet is to use a UIBackgroundMode